# Android Studio 3.5.1 layout issues

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, screen

Every `TextView`, `Button` and control that I drop into the blueprint view goes to the upper left corner.
 I have seen demos that show people dropping controls in and they all go in right below the previous control and it allows them to be resized, center, or any other setting applied.
 I have been able to adjust properties of each control to make them visible, but I have to do it in the text mode of the XML file. 
I'm new to android dev so I don't know all of the properties for the controls yet. 
This doesn't seem to work for me. 
Is there a default setting that needs changed to allow controls to be placed where I put them??
This is extremely frustrating.

Comment: Design mode is not reliable. You have to do in text mode.

Comment: use a relative layout instead of constraint layout

Comment: I would suggest you drag the view into the middle to make it more visible, then set constraints on it.  You can also use `tools:layout_width` and `tools:layout_height` to set a fake width and height if it is too small to drag.